# Hide Column based up Parameter Selected SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, service

I would like to set the visibility of columns based upon the value selected in a parameter.

The problem is I do not want a specific parameter to do this (i.e Hide column X True/False)

My report has several different "departments" who are only interested in certain columns.

What would be the syntax for example to hide the "Sales" column when the "Customer Care" parameter is set?

Answer (score 24):

you can do these works step by step:

1- press right click of your mouse in your favorite column

2- select column visibility

3- from opened window select "Show or hide based on an expression" radio button

4- set an expression for hidden state. for example:

```
 =IIF(Parameters!CustomerCare.Value <> "favorite value", true,false)
```

Comment: You don't need the iif() here. It's redundant. Just do this:

=Parameters!CustomerCare.Value <> "favorite value"

Comment: I tried Parameters!CustomerCare.Value but it is showing me error "The report cannot be displayed. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)"